React Chart js breaks labels when zoom
We currently have a zoom rule for small screens. It applies a zoom to 80%.
But this is breaking the Pie Graph from chart.js.
When we are using large screens, which the page zoom is 100%, we can select the labels to filter in the chart. However, when it's a small screen, which the page zoom is 80%, we can't select the labels to filter it.
Someone can help how to fix it?

<Pie
              data={{
                labels: ['Bug', 'Task', 'Sub-task', 'Story', 'Epic'],
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: 'No. of Issues',
                    data: [
                      findOneTeamIssueTypeCount.data.findOneTeamIssueTypeCount
                        .bug,
                      findOneTeamIssueTypeCount.data.findOneTeamIssueTypeCount
                        .task,
                      findOneTeamIssueTypeCount.data.findOneTeamIssueTypeCount
                        .subtask,
                      findOneTeamIssueTypeCount.data.findOneTeamIssueTypeCount
                        .story,
                      findOneTeamIssueTypeCount.data.findOneTeamIssueTypeCount
                        .epic,
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: [
                      softRed,
                      softYellow,
                      'pink',
                      softBlue,
                      softGreen,
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                  },
                ],
              }}
              options={{
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                  legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                  },
                },
              }}
            />


you can follow the link chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html and in the link read configuration options.
options={{ 
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
plugins: { legend: { position: 'bottom', },
 }, }} 

// Set to false to prevent the chart from maintaining an aspect ratio.

It didn't work, unfortunately.
